# Deploy project online with local server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, deployment, dns

I have reactjs project and I want to deploy it online to a domain from Google domain while the server is my local MySQL server, how could I do that so that the server is my pc and the website running online?

I tried to insert my pc ip address in the DNS in the domain name but I did not get any result and the domain name is already accessed by almost all countries.